# Accelerometer coding not working in all the phones

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am in the process of developing an Android music player which will do the the following actions once a shake action is detected. Actions: 1. Do Nothing 2. Play or Pause 3. Next Song 4. Previous Song

I have created a Service class for the shaking action and it is as follows.

```
public class Shaker extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static final int MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS = 1000;
    private long mLastShakeTime;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private static final String SHAKE_ACTION_PREFERENCE = "shake_action_preference";
    private static final String SHAKE_THRESHOLD_PREFERENCE = "shake_threshold_preference";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) {

                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                float z = event.values[2];

                double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) +
                    Math.pow(y, 2) +
                    Math.pow(z, 2)) - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            Log.d("Acceleration", "Acceleration is " + acceleration + "m/s^2");

                String threshold = sharedPreferences.getString(SHAKE_THRESHOLD_PREFERENCE, "medium");

                float SHAKE_THRESHOLD;
                if(threshold.equals("high"))
                    SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 40.5f;
                else if(threshold.equals("low"))
                    SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 15.5f;
                else
                    SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 25.5f;
                if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                    mLastShakeTime = curTime;
                    Log.d("Shake", "Shake, Rattle, and Roll");

                    String opt = sharedPreferences.getString(SHAKE_ACTION_PREFERENCE, "nothing");
                    Log.d("SharedPreference", opt);
                    Log.d("SharedPreference", threshold);
                    if(opt.equals("play")) {
                        MusicPlayer.playOrPause();
                    } else if(opt.equals("next")) {
                        MusicPlayer.next();
                    } else if(opt.equals("prev")) {
                        MusicPlayer.previous(getApplicationContext(), false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the apk files in actual devices, the shaking function is working only on certain phones and not working for all the mobiles.

I have tried on different mobiles using same Android OS, but it is working in one and not working in the other.

I couldn't figure out why it is like this. Can anybody suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks for telling us. What's the question?

Comment: Sorry for not inlcuding my question before.

Comment: WHat's not working?  Are you not getting accelerometer data?  Are you getting it but it isn't as high as you expect?  Is it coming slower than you expect?  Something else?  We need more details.

Comment: No the accelerometer function for the musicplayer is working, but only in certain mobiles not in all mobiles

Comment: @Frontier2016 You haven't answered Gabe's question: What do you mean with "not working" describe the details. Without further details I doubt no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I had implemented the above class in my logic. I am getting the accelerometer data. But i Installed my app in many devices like Acer,Lenovo, Samsung etc. This shaking action is working in certain phones only. For example I am having Lenovo K4 note, this shaking action is not working in my mobile. But my friend is having Xiaomi M5, this shaking action is working perfectly in that phone. I hope this explains the problem I am facing now

Comment: "Not working"  means after I install the app on my mobile, when I shake the music player is not ding the intended action. At the same time it is doing when i installed it in my friends mobile

Comment: i have the same problem, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  onSensorChanged method is called for any changes but in some devices, it is called more than once.It cause problem in logic of the code.
I solved this problem by adding a private static boolean variable. (It causes this method called once).Once this method executes,this variable becomes true.

```
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
         if(!variable) {
           variable=true;
           ...
           ...
           variable=false;
             }
         }
```

Comment: I have added a private static boolean variable in mmy coding. Still it is not working

Comment: Do you set variable false at the end? I updated my code

Comment: Shokouhix thanks for your continued support, No I haven't set the variable false at the end. I will do that tonight and will let you know the feedback. My mobile is Android 5.1 and my friends mobile is also same OS. But the code is working in his mobile and not working in my mobile.

Comment: I have set variable=false at the end. Still it is not working.